# BGE How to make text appear when winning or losing a game?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm creating a game in the BGE. I want to make a message appear when the player reaches an object which is supposed to be the winning way out of the game.
I also want to make another message pop up when the player reaches a plane I've created and loses the game. Should I should use the collision sensor and then the Message actuator? But how do I make the message pop up on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

The [Message Actuator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/message.html) works with the [Message Sensor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/sensors/types/message.html) to send messages between objects in the game, not to send messages to the player. To show text to the player you need to show a text object or an object that has text as part of it's material, you can also use a [scene as an overlay](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/scene.html) to present the text as part of a HUD.

You could use the messaging system to have an exit sign object become visible by having it change it's visibility when it recieves a message.

[image: game messaging]